# Azure Data Studio: unable to restore SQL Server database - Access Denied

Tags: sql-server, database, docker, restore

I'm in the process of migrating the database from one server to another. When I try to select the backup file (`.bak`) within Docker, I'm getting an 'Access Denied' error. How to provide access permission to the Docker container?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLkrq.jpg)

Comment: Does the `/var/opt/mssql/backup/prod.bak` file exist inside the container? Does the account under which the SQL Server service executes (usually the `mssql` user) have access to the file and its parent folder?

Comment: yes, the file exists inside the container. But I'm using sa SQL credentials to access SQL. How do I use the MAC administrator account since "Windows authentication" is only available?

Comment: could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and what I concluded is that the problem is the file is not in the format it should be, to be precise since I have remote access to my Linux server with GUI, I just copied the .bak file from the windows machine to Linux, which I repeat is not advised way to transfer files form one OS to another. I solved the problem by posting .bak on Google Drive and then generating a download link that I typed in the terminal later.

To generate a proper link from Google Drive I recommend the following guide:
https://bytesbin.com/skip-google-drive-virus-scan-warning-large-files/

When you get the link type in the terminal:
$ curl -L -o The_Name.bak "The_link"

For restoring the database follow this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-restore-backup-in-sql-server-container?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: The issue is not with the format per se but with permissions. I was able to solve the problem by giving read permissions to the bak file with chmod after copying the file from Windows to mac (before copying the file to the container).